# Detect user timezone with php using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datetime, cookies

I am trying to detect the user timezone and to display some content specific the time in that area.

For that purpose I am using jsTimezoneDetect to get the user timezone. After than i submit that timezone to PHP using AJAX and set a cookie with the user timezone.

PHP Code:

```
public function set() {
    $value = Input::get('timezone');
    Cookie::make(Config::get('variables.cookies.timezone'), $value, 30*24*60*60);
}
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var timezone = jstz.determine();
    $.post('timezone/set', {_token: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'), timezone: timezone.name() }, function(data){

    });
});
```

Here i get some strange things:

1) If I get alert(timezone.name()), I see the user timezone, no matter the browser, but in the PHP Controller after I set the Cookie, Chrome does not display me that cookie.

2) It does not work, if I try to get the cookie like that:

```
Cookie::get('timezone');
```

3) It works only in FireFox and only like that:

```
$_COOKIE['timezone'];
```

And one global question. As a timezone i get Europe/Helsinki, but setting is not set in my Windows Datetime Settings neither in php.ini. Where does that come from ?

Comment: Your main code sample is Javascript (client side). It would help if you also show us your PHP controller action (server side).

Comment: Hi @CodingYourLife, i edited my question, but the PHP code is nothing special.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework but the line where you create the cookie looks wrong. Why do you say Config::get('variables.cookies.timezone')? I think it should just be 'variables.cookies.timezone'.

Comment: Config::get('variables.cookies.timezone') - this code is Laravel specific. It loads from the configuration the name of the timezone cookie variable

Comment: But the first attribute is the name of the cookie and how you identify it. That would be "timezone" (just the word). You could create a second Cookie for the "timezonename". Don't know if that solves anything for you

Comment: Do u mean that: Cookie::get('timezone'); ? I was lazy and I have hard-coded the name of the variable :)

Comment: I am making tests on localhost, that's why i am curious where is set Helsinki as timezone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137004/discussion-between-codingyourlife-and-vince-carter).